# Is there a treatment to prevent CV boots from cracking?

Tags: cv-boot

The rear CV boots on my 2010 Subaru Forester are showing signs of becoming brittle, with hairline cracks collecting on the innermost joints. Is there any sort of treatment (silicone spray, for example) that can be used to prolong the time until replacement?

As the accumulating rust might indicate, I live in a wet, cold state with lots of salt on the roads. That's probably not helping the matter.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use silicone sprays or rubber tyre type treatments, however how much longer if any it will make the boots last is debatable. CV boot rubber just like tyres breaks down over time due to the dirt, grime and constant flexing of the material so it's going to fail at some point no matter what you do with it. 
You could also try something like CV Savers which cover the boot to protect it although I've not tried these myself so can't guarantee success with these.

Comment: Interesting idea with the CV Savers -- I'd never heard of them. If grime-driven corrosion and flexing are the primary culprits, it appears that my image of the CV boot rubber 'drying out' over time was simply incorrect.

Comment: Noooo...You were correct also, the rubber does indeed loose its flexibility over time due to drying out as the oils in the material degrade.